# Modify the algorithm to overcome the problem with the minimax for the game

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax, heuristics

Players move in turns. A player moves first. Any player can move to an unoccupied
adjacent square, or can teleport from one end of the board to the other end, given that the other end is not occupied. For example, if A is at second node, and B is at node 5 can go to both 4 and 1. If B wins (occupies 1 cell), game is valued as -1, If A wins (occupies 5 cell), game is valued as +1.

However, there is a problem of loops in this problem, how to modify the algorithm or maybe the heuristic to avoid the problem with this game?

The image of the game:

[image: The image of the game]

Comment: If you want to prohibit loops in your search-tree, add loop-detection.

Comment: Assuming the start position is as your diagram shows, the game looks like B always wins on his first move -- A has to move to cell 2, then B can teleport to cell 1.

Comment: Given the number of states is so small, it's easy just to brute-force this -- set won/loss states to +1 or -1, then repeatedly set any state to +1 if there's a move to a +1 state to +1 or -1 if all moves are to -1 states. Once there's no more changes, you have a solution and any undecided state is a draw by repetition.

Comment: @PaulHankin yes, if we assume that both players play optimally (which minimax algorithm assumes by default), B will always win. The problem with the game is the loops that both players can go forward and backward which creates lots of loops.

Comment: @PaulHankin I just didn't quite understand the solution you suggested, can you provide more details? Thanks.

Comment: I thought I can change the heuristic of the minimax, for example, compute the distance from A to its goal state and from B to its goal state. At that case, both players would go towards their goals.

Comment: minimax doesn't usually have a heuristic, so I don't understand what you mean. If you make an assumption about the best moves to cut down the search tree, I guess it's fine as long as you prove that the assumptions you make are always optimal.

Comment: You ask "how to modify the algorithm". Where is this algorithm that you ask us to modify?

Answer (score 0):

Given the number of states is so small, it's easy just to brute-force this -- set won/loss states to +1 or -1, then repeatedly set any state to +1 if there's a move to a +1 state to +1 or -1 if all moves are to -1 states. Once there's no more changes, you have a solution and any undecided state is a draw by repetition.

Here's a program that does this. You can be a bit cleverer and exploit the symmetry between A and B to both reduce the number of states (and make the code a bit shorter), but this is the straightforward code:

```
def all_states():
    for p in range(2):
        for i in range(5):
            for j in range(5):
                if i == j: continue
                if i == 4 and j == 0: continue # impossible
                yield (p, i, j)

states = list(all_states())

def moves(s):
    p, i, j = s
    if p == 1:
        for p2, i2, j2 in moves((0, 4-j, 4-i)):
            yield 0, 4-j2, 4-i2
    else:
        for i2 in ((i-1)%5, (i+1)%5):
            if i2 != j:
                yield 1-p, i2, j

SCORE = {s: 1 if s[1] == 4 else -1 if s[2] == 0 else 0 for s in states}

change = True
while change:
    change = False
    for s in states:
        if SCORE[s] != 0: continue
        scores = [SCORE[s2] for s2 in moves(s)]
        if s[0] == 0 and 1 in scores:
            SCORE[s] = 1
            change = True
        elif s[0] == 0 and max(scores) == -1:
            SCORE[s] = -1
            change = True
        elif s[0] == 1 and -1 in scores:
            SCORE[s] = -1
            change = True
        elif s[0] == 1 and min(scores) == 1:
            SCORE[s] = 1
            change = True

def board(i, j):
    return ' '.join('A' if n==i else 'B' if n==j else 'x' for n in range(5))

for (p, i, j), sc in SCORE.items():
    print('AB'[p], 'to move: ', board(i, j), ' --', ['B wins', 'draw', 'A wins'][sc+1])
```

Output:

```
A to move:  A B x x x  -- A wins
A to move:  A x B x x  -- A wins
A to move:  A x x B x  -- A wins
A to move:  A x x x B  -- B wins
A to move:  B A x x x  -- B wins
A to move:  x A B x x  -- A wins
A to move:  x A x B x  -- B wins
A to move:  x A x x B  -- A wins
A to move:  B x A x x  -- B wins
A to move:  x B A x x  -- B wins
A to move:  x x A B x  -- A wins
A to move:  x x A x B  -- B wins
A to move:  B x x A x  -- B wins
A to move:  x B x A x  -- A wins
A to move:  x x B A x  -- A wins
A to move:  x x x A B  -- B wins
A to move:  x B x x A  -- A wins
A to move:  x x B x A  -- A wins
A to move:  x x x B A  -- A wins
B to move:  A B x x x  -- A wins
B to move:  A x B x x  -- A wins
B to move:  A x x B x  -- B wins
B to move:  A x x x B  -- A wins
B to move:  B A x x x  -- B wins
B to move:  x A B x x  -- B wins
B to move:  x A x B x  -- A wins
B to move:  x A x x B  -- B wins
B to move:  B x A x x  -- B wins
B to move:  x B A x x  -- B wins
B to move:  x x A B x  -- B wins
B to move:  x x A x B  -- B wins
B to move:  B x x A x  -- B wins
B to move:  x B x A x  -- B wins
B to move:  x x B A x  -- A wins
B to move:  x x x A B  -- B wins
B to move:  x B x x A  -- A wins
B to move:  x x B x A  -- A wins
B to move:  x x x B A  -- A wins
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make the following observations:

- There are at most two valid moves at each turn.
- If the players start such that A is at the left of B, then the one who can make the teleporting move first wins the game. So the best move for them is to walk towards their teleporting square. If they are already there, they should teleport, or if that is not possible, perform the only remaining move (in which case the other player can win on their next move).
- If the players start such that A is at the right of B, the one who reaches their winning square first wins the game. So the best move for them is to walk towards their target square.

In other words, the player's best "strategy" is:

Don't play the (non-teleporting) move *towards* the opponent unless that is the only possible move.

So there is no reason to do minimax, not even a *search*. The best move can be known immediately from the current game state.